# Cannot get $_POST('input') using jQuery .submit()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I was trying to upload a form using jQuery's `submit()` and success in redirect the page to uploadAll.php, but when I was trying to get the input array using `$_POST['inputname']` I can not obtain the value.

I was trying to use `serialize()` but I get confused in where I should put my PHP page reference.

```html
<form id="regForm" action="uploadAll.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  //some inputs and a hidden input here
</form>
```

```js
document.getElementById("regForm").submit(function() {
  var inputValues = $(this).serialize();

  $.ajax({
    url: "uploadAll.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: inputValues
  }).done(function(data) {
    alert(data);
  });
});

return false;
```

Can I just submit without using `serialize()`? It seems my serialize does not work. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Your `return false` is outside the event handler. `serialize()` also works fine, and your logic looks ok. It's hard to say what the exact issue is without seeing the full HTML and PHP logic.

Comment: What is the error its showing in console

Comment: You dont do a `preventDefault()` to stop the form submitting normally

Comment: _Small Note_ If you summarize your code to much it just makes it more difficult for us to be helpful

Comment: As you dont show us the HTML which would show us that you do actually have a field with a `name="inputname"` just do a `var_dump($_POST);` to see what you are actually passing to the PHP

Comment: Thank you for your help Rory, Biswajit, RiggsFolly. There's no error in console. And when i try var_dump($_POST) the output is array(0) { } . I think the problem is in passing the input value to php, not in the input name itself..

Answer (score -1):

trust me, your code is wrong..

try use this code instead:

```
$("#regForm").on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var inputValues = $(this).serialize();

  $.ajax({
    url: "uploadAll.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: inputValues
  }).done(function(data) {
    alert(data);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Syamsoul. I've tried your code, and the output is not directing to uploadAll.php, just the sampe page with Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined. why did you think my code is wrong, is it because how i use submit() method?

Comment: yes.... the submit() method is wrong... you should use jQuery object for listening to `submit` event... if you still want to use pure javascript, you should use code like this `document.getElementById("regForm").addEventListener("submit", function(){  });`..... but if you use jQuery in your website, it is better to use `$("#regForm").on('submit', function(e) { });`

Comment: i was using this code to change button value: <button type="button" id="nextBtn" class="btn blue" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>  and this one: if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
  }. when i tried your code again, it caught an error in console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined. i think i will also check the code from there